# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '...EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(...)'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to generate and apply the migrations, I ran the following on the command line from within project's folder.

```
AuthServer.Infrastructure> dotnet ef database update --context AppIdentityDbContext
AuthServer.Infrastructure> dotnet ef database update --context PersistedGrantDbContext
```

First command succeeded, but for second command I get this output and error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!0,System.Object>>)'.
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Extensions.ModelBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ConfigurePersistedGrantContext>b__0(EntityTypeBuilder`1 grant)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity[TEntity](Action`1 buildAction)
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Extensions.ModelBuilderExtensions.ConfigurePersistedGrantContext(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions) in C:\local\identity\server4\EntityFramework.Storage\src\Extensions\ModelBuilderExtensions.cs:line 148
   at IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts.PersistedGrantDbContext`1.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\local\identity\server4\EntityFramework.Storage\src\DbContexts\PersistedGrantDbContext.cs:line 98
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!0,System.Object>>)'.
```

**nuget packages installed**

```
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.6">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="serilog.extensions.logging" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="serilog.sinks.file" Version="4.1.0" />



<PackageReference Include="identityserver4.entityframework" Version="2.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design" Version="3.1.6">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.6">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.2" />
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Updating identityserver4.entityframework from 2.3.2 to 3.0.0 fixed the problem

Comment: Updating Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore to 5.0.1 fixed a similar error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Verify version with other csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0- 
 preview.1.21102.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; 
 buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.